# VL53L1x gives error VL53L1_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE (-13) when running VL53L1_WaitDeviceBooted

Tags: stm32

I have a [VL53L1x TOF](https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/vl53l1x.html) sensor connected to I2C3 of STM32L432KC.

This is the circuit diagram:
[image]

When we connected this circuit, we are continuously getting maximum value as the output (255, -1, 65535)
On further adding and checking status, I found that VL53L1_WaitDeviceBooted( Dev ); returns -13 (VL53L1_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE), meaning Error reported from IO function but idea as to what is actually the issue.

Majority of the code is auto generated by STM32CubeIDE and we checked voltages at all points and we are getting the voltages that seems appropriate.

XSHUT is getting a voltage of 2.6-2.75V

FYI, We initially had 47k attached to xshut but we reduced the resistance wondering if that is that cause for the device not working.
Also, would this be a software issue, rather than a hardware issue?

Comment: Can you show us the sensor connection? Why you have transistors on the I2C lines? Also, have you checked the I2C data lines with the oscilloscope to see that everything is working ok?

Comment: It could be hardware, software or both. Start with known good hardware. ST have some cheap eval boards.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you fix it?

Comment: @Maxi Passarelli We couldn't fix the issue but one theory we had was a possible issue with the voltage level shifter. We used a BSS138 to do that shifting but the working principle requires the difference in the 2 voltage levels to be at least 0.7V and we were translating between 3.3v to 2.8V. Also, when we contact the manufacturers, I think they said, don't use any level shifters. We didn't get a chance to test it after that. This circuit should work if input voltage is 5V and not 3.3V

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I guess my previous comment answers your question too. We referred to an application circuit that was available online. This worked for us on a previous occasion so we went forward with the same circuit but we believe the issue is with the BSS138 voltage shifter

Comment: Probe the I2C lines with the oscilloscope before and after the transistors, and post the output. We need to check if the I2C is geing transmitted correctly from the STM to the sensor